# terminal returns user git unknown when attempting to execute gitlab rake task

Tags: command-line

I have Gitlab **V2.5** running on Ubuntu 12.04. Git commands (clone, push, pull, etc.) have been successfully running until now.

Suddenly `clone`, `push`, and `pull` give errors that the server is not found.

I found info saying I should try to run `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`, but to do so I must be in the gitlab directory.

I believe my gitlab directory is `/usr/bin` since it contains:

```
git
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack
```

However,when /usr/bin is the current directory and I execute the above command, ubuntu replies that user 'git' is unknown.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Gitlab is a totally separate entity from GitHub. Can you post the link where you got the instructions to run that command? Unless you've been working with GitLab since the beginning you're going have issues. Also, `/usr/bin` is most definitely not your gitlab directory. `/usr/bin` is the place where executables go. When they say your gitlab directory they most likely mean the directory where you were attempting to run `git clone/push/pull` from.

Comment: How did you install gitlab? There are two general possibilities: through package manager (*.deb) or using source code (git cloning, and manual installation)

Comment: I realized that you are talking about gitlab 2.5, so the only possible installation type for this version was `git clone` and etc.. Could you please add output of command `id git` and for `id gitlab`

Comment: Or even for `cat /etc/passwd` if it is not confused you

Comment: RPi Awesomeness - I got this from stackoverflow:

The instruction to run rake are from  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide

Comment: To: c0rp:    gitlab installed using get-apt. The id command for both indicates "no such user".

Comment: @c0rp -- I used a known login and now get the error: "sudo: bundle: command not found."